# unable to call the function "cancelBondProcess()"

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my code, I'm trying to unpair a bluetooth device by calling the function.

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
.....

BluetoothDevice Device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
.......

public void unpair() {
    int state = getBondState();

```
if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING || state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {

    Device.cancelBondProcess();  //Error in this line 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using a non-public API cancelBondProcess(), 
In addition this APIs sounds like it will only cancel the process that is ongoing , i.e when the state is BOND_BONDING, if the device is already bonded it will fail / return error. You will need to removeBond() to remove the bonded device - again this is also non-public API and not recommended if you plan on keeping your application compatible with various versions of android releases.

There are no public APIs currently to accomplish canceling or removing of bond.

Comment: Thanks for replying. If there are no APIs then how i programatically achieve this .

Comment: depending on what you are trying to do you might want to change the approach. Why would you want to remove bonded device ?

Comment: Bcoz my bonded list is getting large and i dont want to search in my bonded list. If i know that i will no longer use the other device why should i keep it ?